# Locust can't recognize my spring boot app in the same docker-compose network

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, locust, stress-testing

I'm running this docker compose file to start a local version of my project and locust to perform some load testing, and I'm supprised how I can't reach my endpoint in the spring boot app.

docker-compose i'm using :

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build: ./colas-crm-back
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - locustnet
    hostname: app
    restart: always

  locust:
    build: ./laod-test-back-end
    ports:
      - "8089:8089"
    networks:
      - locustnet
    depends_on:
      - app
    environment:
      - LOCUST_USERS=10
      - LOCUST_HATCH_RATE=1
      - LOCUST_RUN_TIME=10s
      - LOCUST_HOST=http://app:8080
    restart: always

networks:
  locustnet:
```

from locust trying to reach one of the endpoints and it's not recognized at http://app:8080/:
[image]

the endpoint is like that :

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/dashboard")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DashboardController {
    ...
    @GetMapping("colas-value")
    ResponseEntity<DashboardMetricDto> getColasValue() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(dashboardService.getColasValue());
    }
```

any solution ? to fix it ?

Comment: 404 client error requires a complete http connection and response.  So the server is reachable or it couldn't respond with 404.

Comment: @erik258 yes true i forgot it, i ll check with the request